# Downloading rest objects instead of showing in eclipse browser

Tags: json, spring, eclipse

Everytime i try to show the results from the page, it downloads the results in json format instead of showing them on page.

[image: shows the problem]

It starts to download when i enter the url where the objects/information is stored, instead of showing the page `http://localhost:8082/spring-rest-demo/api/students`

If i run the server and paste this info in postman og google chrome, it does show the correct information without downloading it as a json file.

this is how it should be

[image]

Thank you

Edit:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Student;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class StudentRestController {

    private List<Student> theStudents;

    // define @PostConstruct to load the student data only once!

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadData() {

        theStudents = new ArrayList<>();

        theStudents.add(new Student("Poornima", "Patel"));
        theStudents.add(new Student("Mario", "Rossi"));
        theStudents.add(new Student("Mary", "Smith"));

    }

    // define endpoint for "/Student"-- return list of students

    @GetMapping("/students")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {

        return theStudents;
    }

    // define endpoint for "/Student({studentid}"-- return list of students at index

    @GetMapping("/students/{studentId}")
    public Student getStudent(@PathVariable int studentId) {

        // just index into the list .... keep it simple for now

        return theStudents.get(studentId);
    }

}
```

Comment: please post the code for the /api/students endpoint.

Comment: Just try to use http://localhost:8082/spring-rest-demo/api/students?_json

Answer (score 0):

Try to add produces application/json in @GetMapping annotation.

Comment: It did nok work. Thanks for your help, i will just use some other browser for now. I will fix it when i have more time. Appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: Updated answer please check )

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura , no I tried its not working. @GetMapping(value="/students", produces = "application/json")

Answer (score 0):

*This is a bug in recent versions of Eclipse. Hopefully the Eclipse team will fix it soon* [image: Screenshot of my Spring tool Suit (kind of Eclipse implementation)]